# ¿Que es un driver mysql en java?

Tags: java, jdbc

¿Alguien podría explicarme qué es exactamente un driver y que sería usándolo con mysql?.

Hace poco tiempo que empecé a ver unos vídeos de JBDC y se usa constantemente la palabra "Drivers", y con la respuesta de google sobre que es no me basta para entender como se vincula con mysql.

Este es un código de ejemplo que es lo que aprendí hasta ahora con mysql en java.

```
try {
            //1. Conectarse a la base de datos.
            Connection coneccion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/Java", "root", "root");

            //2.Crear el statement.
            Statement statement = coneccion.createStatement();

            //3.Generar una consulta.
            ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Productos");

            //4.Leer el resulset.       
            while ( resultado.next() ) {

                String idArt = resultado.getString(1);
                String seccionArt = resultado.getString(2);
                String nombreArt = resultado.getString(3);

                System.out.println("ID: " + idArt + ". Seccion: " + seccionArt + ". Nombre: " + nombreArt );

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En términos de Java y JDBC, se le llama driver al jar o librería que permite la comunicación con un motor de base de datos en particular. Sucede que JDBC es un framework de interfaces que provee Java para comunicarse con cualquier motor de base de datos, lo que hace el proveedor del motor de base de datos (o la comunidad) es proveer una implementación de este grupo de interfaces para permitir el acceso y comunicación al motor de base de datos en cuestión.

En tu caso, estás utilizando un driver para conectarte a MySQL, puedes utilizar el [driver (jar) oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) que provee mysql en su página de descarga.

De la misma manera, para comunicarte con otro servidor de base de datos, deberás utilizar el driver (jar) adecuado. Por ejemplo, para comunicarte con una base de datos SQL Server existen dos opciones: 1) el [driver (jar) oficial de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx) y 2) un driver (jar) llamado [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net) que se mantiene por la comunidad, cada uno tiene sus pros y contras y dependerá de esas necesidades particulares la elección de uno u otro.

Comment: Te comento para ver si entendí bien, el jar de mysql es el que provee las interfaces. El paquete sql de Java y Javax(por ejemplo) es implementar estas interfaces?

Comment: Es al revés: jdbc son las interfaces, el jar es la implementación