# ¿Cómo logro guardar una ArrayList en una base de datos y cuando ejecute el programa de vuelta pueda carga la base de datos?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, arraylist, mysql-workbench

La clase de la **ArrayList** es:

```
public class TLista {
public static List<Persona> Lista= new ArrayList<Persona>();

    public TLista(){

    }

public void Add(Persona op){
        Lista.add(op);

}



    public int Buscar(String ced){
        for(int i=0;i<Lista.size();i++){
         if(ced.equals(Lista.get(i).getCedula())){
             return i;
         }   
        }
    return -1;
    }

    public static void Eliminar(String ced){
        for(int i=0;i<Lista.size();i++)
        if(ced.equals(Lista.get(i).getCedula())){
            Lista.remove(i);
        }
    }

   public void Editar(int pos, String ced, String nom, String ape, int edad, String sexo){
       Lista.get(pos).setCedula(ced);
       Lista.get(pos).setNombre(nom);
       Lista.get(pos).setApe(ape);
       Lista.get(pos).setEdad(edad);
       Lista.get(pos).setSexo(sexo);

   }
```

Y la clase **persona** es:

```
public class Persona {
private String Cedula;
private String Nombre;
    private String Apellido;
private int Edad;
    private String Sexo;



public Persona(){

}


public Persona(String ced, String nom,String ape, int edad, String sexo){
        this.Cedula=ced;
        this.Nombre=nom;
        this.Sexo=sexo;
        this.Edad=edad;
        this.Apellido=ape;

}

public String getCedula(){
    return Cedula;
}


public void setCedula(String ced){
    Cedula = ced;
}

public String getNombre(){
    return Nombre;
}


public void setNombre(String nom){
    Nombre = nom;
}


public String getSexo(){
    return Sexo;
}


public void setSexo(String sexo){
    Sexo = sexo;
}

public int getEdad(){
    return Edad;
}


public void setEdad(int edad){
    Edad = edad;
}

    public String getApe(){
    return Apellido;
}


public void setApe(String ape){
    Apellido=ape;
}
```

Me gustaria saber como es que se pudiera lograr una conexión con una base de datos (Mysql) y guardar allí la ArrayList, del mismo modo cargarla.

Answer (score 1):

Para ello necesitas establecer una conexión JDBC puedes seguir este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6741/que-es-un-driver-mysql-en-java/6749#6749)
En lugar de Productos puedes leer y guardar la información de las Personas.

También sería bueno que revisaras el patrón de diseño [DAO](http://codejavu.blogspot.com.co/2013/06/ejemplo-conectando-java-con-mysql.html)

Comment: Otra solución válida es utilizar un ORM (Object Releation Mapper) como hibernate. Aquí https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm un ejemplo bastante explicativo al respecto.